# derivation of rank of tensor from the product of two tensors

Tags: tensors

If $A^p$ is a first rank tensor and $A^pK^{qrs}$ is a 4th rank tensor we have to prove that $K^{qrs}$ is a tensor of rank three?.we can check here clearly that $A^p$ is first rank tensor and $K^{qrs}$ is third rank tensor but i cant understand that why the condition of $A^pK^{qrs}$ is given here??

Comment: I assume you were introduced to the concept of tensors by a definition which requests that "they have to transform correctly". If that is the case, you are supposed to show that $K^{ijk}$ transforms correctly, using the knowledge that $A^p$ and $K^{ijk}$ do. For this I'd say $A^p$ has to be nonzero. If it is, there is a dual tensor $B_p$ such that $A^p B_p = 1$ (summation convention understood).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works:

As $A^p$ is a first rank tensor we know it belongs to some vector space $V$.

As $A^pK^{qrs}$ is a fourth rank tensor we know it belong to, say, $V\otimes V\otimes V\otimes V$.

The crucial observation is that by universality $V\otimes V\otimes V\otimes V\simeq V \otimes (V\otimes V\otimes V)$, so that you may decompose your fourth rank tensor as $A^p\otimes K^{qrs}$ with $A^p\in V$ and $K^{qrs}\in V\otimes V\otimes V$, hence $K^{qrs}$ is a third rank tensor.